# JsonReaderException Encountered when Getting MailBoxUsageDetails with Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am following the GetMailBoxUsageDetail documentation found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getmailboxusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs and I am getting a JsonReaderException.

The full error message is as follows: JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: R. Path '', line 0, position 0.

I have verified I have proper application permissions. I also used Fiddler and see that the content stream is being returned back to the client application, however the Microsoft Graph API appears to try to deserialize the content as Json when it is not.

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var report = GetMailBoxUsageDetailAsync().Result;
        return View();
    }


    public async Task<Report> GetMailBoxUsageDetailAsync(string period = "D7")
    {
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new MsalAuthenticationProvider());

        var report = await graphClient.Reports.GetMailboxUsageMailboxCounts(period)
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();

        return report;

     }
```

I am expecting a Stream Content with the following headers returned: Report Refresh Date,User Principal Name,Display Name,Is Deleted,Deleted Date,Created Date,Last Activity Date,Item Count,Storage Used (Byte),Issue Warning Quota (Byte),Prohibit Send Quota (Byte),Prohibit Send/Receive Quota (Byte),Report Period

Comment: I have listed it a problem with the documentation. However, this may take days to get sorted out.

Comment: I was able to find a reference in their Unit tests but this isn't anything like their documentation.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/tests/Microsoft.Graph.DotnetCore.Test/Requests/Functional/ReportTests.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it appears to be a bug with de-serializing response payload and affects all the endpoints of [Mailbox usage reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailbox-usage-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0)

> It could be reproduced at least in `msgraph-sdk-dotnet` version
>   `1.15.0`

Until it is fixed the following solution could be considered as an alternative option:

```
//Construct and send a request 
var requestUrl = graphClient.Reports.GetMailboxUsageMailboxCounts("D7").Request().RequestUrl;
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(request);
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(request);

// Get the csv report data
var csvData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Vadim, Thank you for sharing this. It follows the same as the Unit Test however I was missing the authentication part. I have opened a bug with MS and will wait for them to resolve.